# OpenCV Android Studio

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have set up OpenCV on Android Studio. I have gone through importing OpenCV for android and adding jniLibs and the project builds successfully and I get "OpenCV loaded" print, when I do a static System.loadLibrary.
However, when I try using most of openCV functions, say equalizeHist, my build fails.
I can successfully import the module using:

```
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
```

When I want to start using the functions in Imgproc though I face this issue:

```
Mat test = new Mat(200, 200, CvType.CV_8UC1);
Imgproc.equalizeHist(test, test);  // cannot resolve symbol equalizeHist
```

Can you help me find out what it is that I did wrong?

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for anyone who is running into the same problem... I had a chance to go back to this problem and it turns out the OpenCV library was not added as dependencies.
This is what I did to fix it:

- File->Project Structure.
- Under Modules, select app.
- Click Dependencies.
- Click +.
- Select Module Dependencies.
- Select :openCVLibrary<301>.

Answer (score 0):

You have loaded "opencv_java3" but you may be missing the dependencies of opencv_java3 .
Please follow the steps

--- from -- /OpenCV-android-sdk/ sdk/ native/ libs 
--- copy libs from there and put them in jniLibs 
--- they already contains libopencv_java3.so and its dependencies

Refer to point 3 in it and instead of libs/ target_arch  make folder jniLibs in src/main and copy to jniLibs/target_arch

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization